# Educational records of congress?

Tags: united-states, congress, education, data-sources

As part of a research project, I'm interested in finding comprehensive educational records of United States politicians in both the House of Representatives and the Senate. This would include what classes they took in both high school and college, and what grades they received. The kind of record I'm looking for could be an official transcript, or an informal list of classes taken. However, I don't know if any such records are publicly available. If they are, where can I find these kinds of data?

If this information isn't aggregated anywhere, I'd also be interested in how one could acquire the educational records of *individual* members of congress.

Comment: [FERPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Educational_Rights_and_Privacy_Act) means you're pretty much not going to get anywhere unless the individual politicians want you to.

Comment: @jwodder Crud, is that true? I thought FERPA only applied to private citizens, not elected representatives, though I hadn't looked into it too deeply.

Comment: If you find the data for Obama, you'll [instantly be world famous](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2012/may/28/obama-ducks-calls-to-release-his-collegiate-transc/).